# How to get all the selected with checkbox rows in a MUI table

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I am using [the MUI table](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/#sorting-amp-selecting) (not DataGrid) with sorting & selecting. Everything works fine but I'm unable to figure out how to get the values of all the items selected by checkbox.

Here's a snippet of the table's code:

```
<Paper elevation={0} sx={{ width: "100%", mb: 2 }}>
  <Toolbar
    sx={{
      pl: { sm: 2 },
      pr: { xs: 1, sm: 1 },
      ...(selected.length > 0 && {
        bgcolor: (theme) =>
          alpha(
            theme.palette.primary.main,
            theme.palette.action.activatedOpacity
          ),
      }),
    }}
  >
    <Typography
      sx={{ flex: "1 1 100%" }}
      color="inherit"
      variant="subtitle1"
      component="div"
    >
      {selected.length} selected
    </Typography>
  </Toolbar>

  <TableContainer>
    <Table sx={{ minWidth: 750 }} size={dense ? "small" : "medium"}>
      <EnhancedTableHead
        numSelected={selected.length}
        order={order}
        orderBy={orderBy}
        onSelectAllClick={handleSelectAllClick}
        onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
        rowCount={rows.length}
      />
      <TableBody>
        {visibleRows.map((row, index) => {
          const isItemSelected = isSelected(row.name);
          const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;

          return (
            <TableRow
              hover
              onClick={() => {
                fillCurrentSelected(row);
              }}
              color="primary"
              role="checkbox"
              tabIndex={-1}
              key={row.email}
              selected={isItemSelected}
              sx={{ cursor: "pointer", fontSize: "0.85em" }}
            >
              <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                <Checkbox
                  color="primary"
                  onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row.name)}
                  checked={isItemSelected}
                  size="small"
                  inputProps={{
                    "aria-labelledby": labelId,
                  }}
                />
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell
                component="th"
                sx={{ fontSize: "0.9em" }}
                id={labelId}
                color="primary"
                scope="row"
                padding="none"
                onClick={() => {
                  setOpen(true);
                  setOptSelected(0);
                }}
              >
                {row.name}
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          );
        })}
        {emptyRows > 0 && (
          <TableRow
            style={{
              height: (dense ? 33 : 53) * emptyRows,
            }}
          >
            <TableCell colSpan={6} />
          </TableRow>
        )}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  </TableContainer>
</Paper>;
```

I have used datagrid before and it was pretty straight foward. I have also tried searcging for the [Table](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/table/), [TableBody](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/table-body/), or [TableCell](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/table-cell/) props.

Somebody help as it would be next to impossible to start all over again using [Datagrid](https://mui.com/toolpad/reference/components/data-grid/).

Comment: Would this `handleSelect` logic from official example help? https://codesandbox.io/s/rnc8jm?file=/Demo.tsx:7778-7854

Comment: @Tuan Thanks. But there is only `handleSelectAllClick` in the example for all the checkboxes. I need for a single checkbox

Comment: Sorry i mean to say `handleClick`, it does have the logic to properly store the selected rows into a React state.

Comment: I can't believe I hadn't seen that! Thanks so much!